# SQL expand table to merge filed with duplicates Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some duplicates Data, I want to merge the field in one table.

My data currently looks like this:

```
name       job1        Unit1_Level1       Unit1__Level2
-------------------------------------------------------
A          Teacher     Infomation      Information_office
A          Staff       Secretary       Secretary_office
B          Teacher     Finacial        Finacial_office
C          Teacher     Engineer        Engineer_office
C          Staff       Library         Library_office
D          Staff       Library         Library_office
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
name       job1        Unit1_Level1       Unit1__Level2       job2     Unit2_Level1     Unit2__Level2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A          Teacher     Infomation      Information_office     Staff    Secretary        Secretary_office
B          Teacher     Finacial        Finacial_office
C          Teacher     Engineer        Engineer_office        Staff    Library          Library_office
D          Staff       Library         Library_office
```

Hope any one can help me, thanks!

Comment: Be great to see what have you tried.

Comment: How many jobs can a person have? What makes you make teacher job1 and staff job2? Is there some rule applied or would job1=staff, job2=teacher be just as fine? What have you tried yourself and where have you got stuck? What exactly is the problem you want an answer for? You haven't even asked a question.

Comment: As you haven't replied yet, here is what I think: The table as is is as it should be; a row clearly relates one job to one person allowing for a person to have multiple jobs (1, 2, 3, how many ever). You want to show this with one row per person, however. Typically, the database and SQL are just the means to get the data (e.g. `select * from mytable`) and how you display it is dealt with in the application or website retrieving that data. So you'd just use your programming language in order to fill the grid. But you *can* do this in SQL. Look up "pivot" or "conditional aggregation" for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row_number() function to numerate each iteration (job) of the same person. With that number you can return a select of their fist iteration, and join them their second iteration .... or even join a third, fourth, ... iteration.

```
with cte as (
  select name, job1, Unit1_Level1, Unit1_Level2,
         row_number() over (partition by name order by job1 desc) as iteration
  from MyTable
)
select i1.name, i1.job1, i1.Unit1_Level1, i1.Unit1_Level2,
       i2.job1 as job2, i2.Unit1_Level1 as Unit2_Level1, i2.Unit1_Level2 as Unit2_Level2,
       i3.job1 as job3, i3.Unit1_Level1 as Unit3_Level1, i3.Unit1_Level2 as Unit3_Level2
from cte as i1
     left join cte as i2 on i2.name = i1.name and i2.iteration = 2
     left join cte as i3 on i3.name = i1.name and i3.iteration = 3
where i1.iteration = 1
```

PS: You haven't indicated in which order do you want to return the jobs of the same person, so I have used **job1 desc** in order to return them as your sample data : first Teacher and second Staff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then job1 end) as job1_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Unit1_Level1 end) as Unit1_Level1_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Unit1_Level2 end) as Unit1_Level2_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then job1 end) as job1_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Unit1_Level1 end) as Unit1_Level1_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Unit1_Level2 end) as Unit1_Level1_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by job1 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name
```